# Issue with deleting a binary file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, binaryfiles

I'm trying to delete a binary file from a directory in C#. But the File.Delete() method seems to work in misterious ways.

You see, when I try to delete the specified file from my directory, it doesn't work and the file is not deleted. However, when I open the directory where I have the file and then I execute my project to try to delete the file again, the file IS actually getting deleted and does not appear afterwards. What can be the issue?

This is my code:

```
currentDB.listTab = delTab.backup;
String fullPath = path + "\\" + delTab.delete;
File.Delete(fullPath);
txtStats.Text = "Deleted";
load_tables();
show_files();
```

I ask for the name of the file (delTab.delete) on a different window, and then I return the name in order to delete the file.

Comment: what value is contained in the path variable

Comment: @preciousbetine The full path of the directory where the file is located

Comment: Any exception gets thrown by File.Delete?

Comment: @Etienne de Martel   no exception for File.Delete

Comment: please can you type the full path to the file as a comment

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel none at all

Comment: @preciousbetine C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\Test\\Example

Comment: what is in the del variable

Comment: you delete file which belongs to your account?

Comment: @preciousbetine Is an instance of a new WinForm in which I ask for the name of the target file, then I also retrieve a list of file names from the same directory that won't be deleted.

Comment: @Frenchy Yes it is

Comment: have you special permission from your folder? its the last idea problem of permission

Comment: try using Path.Combine(path,del);

Comment: @preciousbetine It somehow works now, thanks